# Perl : web graphic interface, which library?

Tags: perl, interface

I've wrote perl scripts to query my network (cisco switchs) in SNMP
and I want to display informations (speed, @mac, duplex...) found by the script on an web interface.
I want a sketch of the switch, with green ports, if all is ok, orange if there is a problem, on mouse over, or on the side, the differents informations about the port.
I would like something like that :
[image: Cisco switch]
And color of the ports dynamically change depending on the answer of the perl scripts.

Thanks, bye.

Comment: You do not know the basics. CGI is not about HTML. It's about making dynamic HTTP responses. Such a response can be an image, it is not limited to anything. Your CGI program is responsible to act on the HTTP request's input, e.g. query parameters, and generate an appropriate response.

Comment: Ok I see, I just found tutorials learning how to print hello world in the browser. Do you have a good Perl/CGI tuto ? I want to modelise a switch with his ports....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be to use a CGI script with ImageMagick or GD to mark on a template graphic and schedule a reload frequency on the image using the Refresh HTTP header.

The modern way would be to use AJAX methods to regularly download current status, and then draw appropriate elements on the template image.  The AJAX back-ends can be written as CGI scripts, too.

Comment: @eouti, CGI and CGI.pm are not synonymous.  CGI.pm is just one library that makes CGI scripts easier to write.  It sounds like you are starting from the very beginning of a long learning curve.  Check out Ovid's CGI Course to get started.  http://jdporter.perlmonk.org/cgi_course/

Answer (score -2):

First of all, the cgi idea isn't bad. You can visualize your network stats on many clients. And they only need a browser. E.g http://raphaeljs.com/ nice chart, graph etc js lib.
I've build such a thing myself. Networksensors are pushing informations to a database. And a webfrontend (it don't have to be perl) is aggregating and displaying the (avg/peak/amount) traffic over time. It works

Comment: Nothing available like Java applet for the web in Perl ?